# How to add custom error in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to call custmo error in controller, that after to show in template?

For example, I have condition:

```
if($id == 500){
   // call error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call just the error in the controller and abort, you do

```
abort(500, 'Internal error');
```

If you want to return an error

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['error' => 'was 500']);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want to add custom errors where?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by catching the error in the **Handler** (*app/Exceptions/Handler.php*), something like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e){

    // other errors here by your wish

    // custom error message
    if ($e instanceof \ErrorException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }else{
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Note that you need 500 template in *resources/views/errors/500.blade.php* (create if it doesnt exist, and fill if with your data or iformation about the exception)